# AVSpeechSynthesizer - iOS 12.3 Doesn't work (it works fine with iOS 12.2)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm testing AVSpeechSynthesizer and looked around plenty of examples and tutorials.

All of them work fine on iOS 12.2, but doesn't work on iOS 12.3 (including 12.3.1).

Anyone passed this?

Edit:

I've tried to run this app

https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/master/SpeakEasy

And this doesn't work on my iOS 12.3 (XR) devices while works fine on iOS 12.2 (7+).
BTW, this works perfectly on simulators.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Elaborate upon your problem. This isn't a question. At least tell us where things are going wrong. Do some work and debugging. You can't just say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample function that should work. You need to import AVKit first with the following code:

```
import AVKit
```

Here is a demo function which should work:

```
func saySomething(utterance: String!) {
        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: utterance)
        let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
        utterance.voice = voice
    }
```

You can then call this function anywhere you'd like by passing in the text you want it to speak like so:

```
saySomething(utterance: "Hello I am a robot")
```

Comment: https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/master/SpeakEasy
Please check this repository. This works fine on simulators.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by myself.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

From iOS 12.3, audio session should be set active to make synthesizer work.